# probability of failure bayes theorem

Tags: statistics, bayes-theorem

Consider a 3-component series system shown below. The failure events of the components are assumed to be statistically independent of each other. The probability of failure of each component is 0.1. What is the probability that Component 1 has failed under the system failure? Use Bayes’ rule to find the solution.

o----comp.1----comp.2----comp.3----o

I'm not sure why I have to use Bayes' theorem...shouldn't the answer just be 0.1?

Comment: Let C=(Component 1 failed) and S=(System failed), you are asked to compute P(C|S)=P(C)/P(S) (since C implies S), not P(C).

Comment: Because it is conditional on the event that the system has failed, i.e. at least one of the components has failed.